# run javascript functions when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have several JavaScript functions that need to run when the page loads to fetch content. I have tried to use window.onload to call the function but it hasn't worked.

Basically, need to run several functions after the page finishes loading but only once.

I have this so far but it didn't work

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=serverstats
window.onload=latestnews
</script>
```

Comment: That's why there exist [advanced event handler models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Comment: Variables can only contain one value. You should probably brush up on the basics a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your main issue:

```
window.onload=serverstats  #sets window.onload to serverstats
window.onload=latestnews   #sets window.onload to latestnews and removes the reference to serverstats
```

You can fix this by doing:

```
oldOnload = window.onload;
window.onload=function() {
    oldOnload();
    serverstats();
    latestnews();
};
```

However, as the question is tagged with JQuery, I would recommend using it and doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    serverstats();
    latestnews();
});
```

Comment: Using `onload` directly can be pretty bad in some environments that either set the onload first or assume to be the exclusive owner...

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle both by using the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", serverstats);
window.addEventListener("load", latestnews);
```

This doesn't work in IE8 and earlier though, which use:

```
window.attachEvent("onload", serverstats);
window.attachEvent("onload", latestnews);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `onload` value. Write a function that calls both of them instead.

```
window.onload = function() {
    serverstats();
    latestnews();
};
```

Comment: This is one way to break integration with many other libraries (and/or SharePoint...). However, it doesn't deserve a -1 so..

Comment: @pst: Yeah, the other solutions are better. If you're in the mood for upvoting, send one to Drew: he posted the non-jQuery solution, which is always nice to know.